# Перестает работать Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Использую такой скрипт для занесения даты изменения листа в ячейку. 
Проблема в том, что скрипт работает не при всех изменениях. Изменений в файле много. 
Не могу понять в чем проблема и что делать

```
function onEdit(e) {
// Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
var sheet_name = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
var range = e.range;
var column = range.getColumn()
var d = new Date()
if (range.getValue() != '' && sheet_name != 'Template' && sheet_name != 'Template_Rus' && sheet_name != 'Hierarchy' && 
 column >= 6) {
e.source.getActiveSheet()
.getRange('A2')
.setValue(d.getMonth()+1 + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear())
}
else if (sheet_name != 'Template' && sheet_name != 'Template_Rus' && sheet_name != 'Hierarchy' && column >= 6) {
range.clearNote()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Причин может быть много. Вот очевидные из них:

- Каков тип триггера? С большой вероятностью это Simple trigger, но все равно, какой?
- К пункту выше. Кто хозяин триггера? Анонимус не может получить ддоступ к такому, если это простой триггер.
- Где проверка на ошибки? Положите все в "лукшко" `function handler(e){try{...}catch(err){...}}`
- На триггеры не гарантировано выполнение. Самый успешный запуск, который я видел - 80 изменений в минуту. Обычно, не больше 30.
- `e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();` быть не может. Почитайте мои комментарии по поводу этого на этом форуме. Сделайте `e.range.getSheet().getName();`
- `range.getValue() != '' && sheet_name != 'Template' && sheet_name != 'Template_Rus' && sheet_name != 'Hierarchy' && 
  column >= 6` Кто кроме вас будет разбираться в этом!? Выносите в отдельную функцию.